# Orthogonal initializer is being called on a matrix with more elements: Slowness may result

Tags: tensorflow, keras, seq, tensorflowjs-converter

tensorflowjs version: 0.11.7
Keras version: 2.0.4

I am trying to run Keras converted model on browser. For conversion I have used tensorflowjs converter, the conversion went fine. However, at load time,

> Orthogonal initializer is being called on a matrix with more than 2000
>   (2560000) elements: Slowness may result.

This message pops up and the memory blowup happens and lastly the browser stops working.
Following is my keras model architecture:[image]
As we run the tensorflowjs code to load the aforementioned model, following warning pops up:[image]

Is there a way to speed up the Orthogonal initialization process, so the model gets loaded in less time and with less effort?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please do a snippet in http://www.codepen.io and put the link here? That will be easier to see what is wrong with the code